# ASP.NET Forms authentication allow direct link

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have an ASP.NET MVC site currently working with forms authentication.
I want to add the ability for some users to use a special link I send them, this link will grant them direct access to the site without having to login. Problem is, that even the call to my contoller still goes through the login page.
Any ideas on how to make this direct login without giving up on the forms authentication for all other users?

Comment: Have your own authentication filter. In the filter, check if the url matches your secret url and then set the `IPrincipal` for the current request in `HttpContext` or even issue your own forms cookie. Too short for an answer, so I put it in the comment.

Comment: How are you securing the site right now?

Comment: @DavidG: forms authentication, he said it in the very first sentence.

Comment: @WiktorZychla I meant (my fault for being vague) how is access to certain controllers/actions being restricted? e.g. using the `Authorize` attribtue.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I don't use Authorize, I just see that any call is first routed to the AccountController to LogOn method, as defined in the loginUrl in web.config.  @Wiktor , I didn't follow your meaning would appreciate a more detailed one (I'm new to MVC).

Comment: Google for authentication filters examples, there are plenty.